# EclipseLink MOXy: Bindings working with Unmarshaller but not with Binder

Tags: binding, jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

I use the same bindings configuration for unmarshalling once using the Unmarshaler and once using a Binder. The first approach works fine, the second throws an Exception. What's the reason?

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:root xmlns:foo="http://www.domain.org/foo">test</foo:root>
```

**Bindings:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
 xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
 package-name="test">

<xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://www.domain.org/foo">
  <xml-ns prefix="foo" namespace-uri="http://www.domain.org/foo" />
</xml-schema>

<java-types>        
  <java-type name="Root">
    <xml-root-element name="root"/>
    <java-attributes>
      <xml-value java-attribute="text"/>
    </java-attributes>
  </java-type>
</java-types>

</xml-bindings>
```

**Classes:**

```
package test;

public class Root {

private String text;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Map<String, Object> jaxbContextProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
jaxbContextProperties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "bindings.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] { Root.class}, jaxbContextProperties);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Root root = (Root)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("input.xml"));
Binder<Node> binder = jaxbContext.createBinder();
root = (Root) binder.unmarshal(document);
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507- 3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element foo:root was not found in the project]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) you just need to make sure your `DocumentBuilderFactory` is namespace aware by changing your code to look like the following:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new File("input.xml"));
```